# Tikz, anchor point and intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, anchor

I'm using the following LaTeX code for Tikz:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[    noeud/.style={draw, circle}, 
                            triangle/.style={isosceles triangle, anchor=apex, 
                                             draw, shape border rotate=90,
                                             minimum size = 1cm}, 
                            scale=1]
    \node (A) at (-1.5, -2) {};
    \node (B) at (1.5, -2) {};
    \node[noeud] (r) at (0, 0) {$r$};
    \node[triangle] at (A) {$A$};
    \node[triangle] at (B) {$B$};
    
    \coordinate(Ar) at (intersection of r and r--A);
    \draw (Ar)--(-1.5, -2);

    \coordinate(Bd) at (intersection of r and r--B);
    \draw (Bd)--(1.5, -2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to draw a straight line between the node r and the top of the two triangles. But, I'm not able, in a readible way, to finalize my Tikz code.

Is someone know what's wrong with mine?

Here is an image of what I get and what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code a full and compilable snippet. If I just add the necessary parts to the code, I cannot reproduce the problem you get. But, why don't you just name the triangular nodes, for example `\node[triangle] (T1) at (A) {$A$};` and then just connect them using `\draw (r) -- (T1.north);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can easily positioning everything with `positioning` library and use `apex` anchor to stop the connections.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    noeud/.style={draw, circle}, 
    triangle/.style={isosceles triangle, anchor=apex, 
                    draw, shape border rotate=90,
                  minimum size = 1cm}, 
                            scale=1]
%    \node (A) at (-1.5, -2) {};
%    \node (B) at (1.5, -2) {};
    \node[noeud] (r) at (0, 0) {$r$};
    \node[triangle, below left=2cm and 1cm of r] (A) {$A$};
    \node[triangle, below right=2cm and 1cm of r] (B) {$B$};
    
%    \coordinate(Ar) at (intersection of r and r--A);
    \draw (r)--(A.apex) (r)--(B.apex);

%   \coordinate(Bd) at (intersection of r and r--B);
%    \draw (Bd)--(1.5, -2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Add `outer sep=0pt, line join=round` to the options for `triangle` to get a better connection between the lines and the nodes.